# Android - Docking ImageView to the bottom of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, imageview

I have an Android app and I am trying to create the following layout in code:

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

     private Context mContext;

     public MyLayout(Context context) {
         super(context);
         mContext = context;
         this.build();
     }

     private void build() {
         LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(mContext);
         parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

         GridView gridView = new GridView(this.mContext);
         gridView.setNumColumns(2);
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                 MarginLayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
         parent.addView(gridView);

         addView(parent);
     }
}
```

How can I add the ImageView so that it is docked at the bottom of the LinearLayout?

Comment: why don't you use a XML file to implement the layout?

Comment: the application i am developing on builds this screen in code, however i am open to using xml. How would I do this in XML?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xml layout like the following, and then load it with setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name) inside your onCreate method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/yourGridViewID"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/yourImageViewID"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer this code :

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

 private Context mContext;
 private LinearLayout parent;
 public MyLayout(Context context) {
     super(context);
     mContext = context;
 parent = new LinearLayout(mContext);
     this.build();
 }

 private void build() {

     parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

     GridView gridView = new GridView(this.mContext);
     gridView.setNumColumns(2);
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
             MarginLayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
     ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this.mContext);
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams params2 = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
             MarginLayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     params2.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
     imageview.setLayout(params2);
     parent.addView(gridView);
     parent.addView(imageview);

     addView(parent);
 }
}
```

Comment: params2.gravity -> gravity can't be resolved because it's not a part of ViewGroup.